# persistent accidental icons on gnome (fallback) top panel

Tags: gnome, icons, panel

I accidentally dragged (twice)  the "shut down" icon onto the top bar, and am not managing to get of them. 
I already tried:
1. pressing alt or alt+win and right clicked them (nothing happens) 
2. dragging them onto the desktop (they bounce right back)
3. dragging them directly into the trash bin (they bounce back) 
4. downloading the gnome tweak tool (found no helpful option there).

Are there any other options? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

p.s. I am working on Ubuntu 11.10 with gnome fallback.

Comment: did you tried to right click on the icon? without pressing any other keyboard button?

Answer (score 1):

The Alt+rightclick combination did not work because I had set the leftAlt key to toggle between my keyboards (this I had done under keyboard layout options).

Having disabled that option, I was able to normally use the Alt+rightclick combination to remove the unwanted icons.